# Possible tkinter and opencv2 bug?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

I am encountering a problem where I'm wanting to create and destroy windows using OpenCV using Tkinter buttons.

I also will add that when I run `pip list` it comes up with `opencv-python version: 4.3.0`

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import *


class visualRecognition():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        self.windowOpen = True
        self.lastH_min, self.lastH_max, self.lastS_min, self.lastS_max, self.lastV_min, self.lastV_max = 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0
    
        self.createWindow()

    def createWindow(self):
        self.windowOpen = True

    def destroyWindow(self):
        self.lastH_min, self.lastH_max, self.lastS_min, self.lastS_max, self.lastV_min, self.lastV_max = self.lastH_min, self.lastH_max, self.lastS_min, self.lastS_max, self.lastV_min, self.lastV_max
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        self.windowOpen = False
        
    def main(self):
        while True:
            ret, frame = self.cap.read()
            #code here to get results and draw a nice rectangle :)
            hStack = np.hstack([frame,results])

            if self.windowOpen == True:
                cv2.imshow("hello world", hStack)
                cv2.waitKey(1)


class GraphicalUserInterface():
    def __init__(self):
        
        #variables
        self.calibrationButtonClicked = False
        self.calibrationCounter = 0 
        #main window configurations and settings
        self.window = Tk()

        self.calibrationButton = Button(self.window,
                text = "Calibration",
                command = lambda: self.calibrationMode(),
                font = ("Comic Sans", 30),
                fg = "black",
                bg = "#eb7134",
                activebackground= "#c25d2b")
        self.calibrationButton.grid(row=2, column=6, pady=(40,0))

        self.window.mainloop()


    def calibrationMode(self):
        if self.calibrationCounter == 0:
            visualRec = visualRecognition()
            visualRec.main()
            self.calibrationButtonClicked = True
            self.calibrationCounter += 1
            print(f"Initial calibration in progress")
        else:
            if self.calibrationButtonClicked == False:
                self.calibrationButtonClicked = True
                visualRec.createWindow()
                print(f"Calibration in progress")

            elif self.calibrationButtonClicked == True:
                self.calibrationButtonClicked = False
                visualRec.destroyWindow()
                print(f"Calibration over")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GraphicalUserInterface()
```

When you first open the application and press the `Calibration` button, it opens up the OpenCV windows perfectly but then when you click on anywhere Tkinter window, it freezes for a second and then runs into a fatal error.

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x00005104 (most recent call first):
  File "main.py", line 94 in main
  File "main.py", line 196 in calibrationMode
  File "main.py", line 154 in <lambda>
  File "D:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883 in __call__
  File "D:\Python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1420 in mainloop
  File "main.py", line 176 in __init__
  File "main.py", line 222 in <module>
```

Comment: Use state=Disabled and state=Normal for button in calibrationMode function.

Comment: @toyotaSupra but I need to be able to press on the calibration button in order to destroy the windows opened up by OpenCV

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the full error message. When I run your code, I get `NameError: name 'results' is not defined`. Is that the error message you have?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I did not include my whole code, it would've been too long, I tried condensing it down to what was most crucial. After some talks with myself and the voices, I realized that my infinite loop in my first class takes up the whole thread so when I try and use anything outside the infinite loop it crashes because it has no thread to use (ignore my bad use of computer knowledge) my whole code is on my github, under TurretShootsPlanes

Comment: Ah yes, infinite loops do not do well with `tkinter`. But I was asking whether you included your whole _error message_; the error message that's in your question right now is incomplete.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin i'll edit my code to include it

Comment: As @SylvesterKruin said. This is almost certainly related to your use of an infinite loop.